# How can I proxy Wordpress with node-http-proxy, my wordpress redirects to a different port

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I want to proxy my Wordpress which is hosted at localhost at port 8888.

When I http to this node-http-proxy as follows http:// localhost:8001/ it re-directs to http:// localhost:8888/. I mean that Wordpress does the re-direct because Wordpress thinks its on port 8888.

How can I reverse proxy this correctly?

```
var util = require('util'),
    http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//
// Create a new instance of HttProxy to use in your server
//
var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8888
  });
}).listen(8001);
```

Does this issue help? https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/pull/376 but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am trying to have a similar setup using nginx as reverse proxy, and WordPress redirect is screwing up everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to go into your wordpress admin settings and set the site URL parameter to `http://localhost:8001`.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want to do, this can work but... I want the reverse proxy to work it out

Comment: Keep in mind the reverse proxy isn't going to fix any absolute URLs wordpress sticks in your HTML. Ditto for RSS feeds. Basically, I think ultimately you will not be able to make this proxying 100% transparent to wordpress.

Answer (score -2):

Define `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` in wp-config.php to point to the proxy url.

eg.,

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/blog/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/blog/');
```